# Как по имени пользователя получить данные из базы и подсчитать их?

Tags: php, mysql

Мне необходимо из базы данных по имени пользователя получить количество положительных и отрицательных отзывов, где положительные имеют статус **ok**, а отрицательные **trush**

Вот так обращаюсь к базе

```
$reviews = $db->super_query("SELECT * FROM ".PREFIX."_users_balance WHERE name='".$row['autor']."'",true);
```

Как далее получить результат для конкретного пользователя `$row['autor']` из поля **status** и сложить результат?

Т.е. в таблице `PREFIX."_users_balance` могут быть сотни записей про одного юзера `$row['autor']`, как со статусом **ok**, так и **trush**, а получить в итоге нужно числа.

Кроме того, информации о пользователе может и не быть в таблице или статус может иметь иное значение.

Помогите сделать верный запрос.

Спасибо!

Comment: `"SELECT count(*) as ok_count, (SELECT count(*) FROM ".PREFIX."_users_balance WHERE name='".$row['autor']."' and status = 'trush') as trush_count FROM ".PREFIX."_users_balance WHERE name='".$row['autor']."' and status = 'ok'"` можно как-то так

Comment: Спасибо. Как в php получить значение результатов не пойму?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте

`$reviews = $db->super_query("SELECT count(*) FROM ".PREFIX."_users_balance WHERE name='".$row['autor']."' AND status='ok'",true);`

`$reviews = $db->super_query("SELECT count(*) FROM ".PREFIX."_users_balance WHERE name='".$row['autor']."' AND status='trash'",true);`

Разница - в функции `count(*)`, которая и возвращает число, и в условии `status='ok'` или `status='trash'`. Ну, и имя колонки, которая хранит статус, надо проверить.

**Дополнение, написанное после комментария.**

> Как получить результат

А как Вы обычно получаете результат при обращении к базе? в результате вызова count(*) вернется рекордсет, состоящий из одной безымянной колонки, которая содержит одно число - счетчик.

Если колонке надо дать имя - можно использовать конструкцию `select count(*) as cnt1 from ...` - у колонки появилось имя cnt1

Для того, чтобы уменьшить сложность понимания и разделить задачу на части - имеет смысл использовать какой то 'дружественный' клиент базы данных, в котором можно написать и отладить все sql-запросы, прежде чем вставлять их в php. Я рекомендую mysql workbench, он легко гуглится.

> Как сделать это одним запросом к базе.

Интересный вопрос. Дело в том, что Вы обращаетесь к базе дважды, с двумя разными условиями.

К сожалению, способ, который я придумал - не очень изящный. Фактически, он склеивает два запроса в один, используя оператор union.

Приведу пример, из которого Вы сможете переписать код для своего случая:

Пусть я хочу определить кол-во компьютеров в двух подсетях.

Я делаю это запросом

`select count(*) from IpList where Ip like '192.168.10.%'`

для подсети 192.168.10.x, и запросом

`select count(*) from IpList where Ip like '192.168.12.%'`

для подсети 192.168.12.x

Теперь скомбинируем два запроса в один:

```
    select count(*) as cnt1,        0 as cnt2  from IpList where Ip like '192.168.10.%'
    union
    select        0 as cnt1, count(*) as cnt2  from IpList where Ip like '192.168.12.%'
```

В результате вернется 2 столбца и 2 строки с числами вроде такого:

```
    cnt1    cnt2
    3       0
    0       11
```

Если из первой строки взять cnt1, а из второй - cnt2, то получится как раз то, что нужно.

В Вашем случае условиями в первом запросе будет `status='ok'`, а во втором `status='trash'`

Comment: А одним запросом к базе это не выполнить? Я не понял, как в итоге вывести результат :(